# Chop of n elements from the head of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am learning Javascript at Freecodecamp. This challenge is to chop of n elements from the head of an array.  My code works, except when slicing at 1.

I have been at this for a while, unfortunately I do not have my head around for loops sufficiently to find my own solution. I feel its best I know why this went wrong, rather than discover an alternative method. Many thanks in advance.

```
function slasher(arr, howMany) {
// it doesn't always pay to be first
 var newArr = [];

for (i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {


if (arr[i] <= howMany) {
  return arr.slice(howMany);
}
else {
return arr;
}
}
}
slasher(["burgers", "fries", "shake"], 1);

expected output
slasher([1, 2, 3], 2) should return [3].
slasher([1, 2, 3], 0) should return [1, 2, 3].
slasher([1, 2, 3], 9) should return [].
slasher([1, 2, 3], 4) should return [].
slasher(["burgers", "fries", "shake"], 1) should return ["fries", "shake"].
slasher([1, 2, "chicken", 3, "potatoes", "cheese", 4], 5) should return 
["cheese", 4].
```

Comment: What output do you expect and what are you getting?

Comment: You want to chop off from the head of a *string* or an *array*? Did you notice that your `for` loop never loops more than once? Why do you compare the array elements (the strings) with `howMany`? Please provide examples of input/output.

Comment: @AmanB I've edited my question to show the expected output. Each output  worked, apart from slasher(["burgers", "fries", "shake"], 1); I now know that the if statement should've been [i]<=howMany and not arr[i}.

Comment: @Charcow, thanks for having added examples. Now the question is why you need a function at all, because it already exists: The Array method `slice` does the job. There is no need for anything else, or is there? `return arr.slice(howMany);` is all the function would need to have to do.

Comment: @trincot as soon as ele posted his response below I was able to go to the answer and discussion page and saw that it is indeed much simpler than I made it out to be. Part of learning I suppose, for loops have been prominent in my last few challenges so I  assumed it would be something that was required.

Comment: I don't know where the challenge originated, but could it be that you were not supposed to use `slice` in the solution, but had to implement that logic yourself? Then it would make more sense as an exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check for the length of that array:**

```js
function slasher(arr, howMany) {
  return arr.slice(howMany);
}

console.log(slasher([1, 2, 3], 2)); // should return [3].
console.log(slasher([1, 2, 3], 0)); // should return [1, 2, 3].
console.log(slasher([1, 2, 3], 9)); // should return [].
console.log(slasher([1, 2, 3], 4)); // should return [].
console.log(slasher(["burgers", "fries", "shake"], 1)); // should return ["fries", "shake"].
console.log(slasher([1, 2, "chicken", 3, "potatoes", "cheese", 4], 5));// should return ["cheese", 4].
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I too don't understand my logic, but this worked. Today has been an eureka moment with for loops, and now I see that I just needed to point to the index, this worked so thank you.

Comment: what is the purpose of the loop here? What's wrong with just `return arr.slice(howMany)`?

Comment: This does not make sense. Why loop if you always exit it? This should NOT be an accepted answer.

Comment: Now I've completed the challenge I see that it wasn't required and that there is a much easier way of doing this.

Comment: @trincot it worked for what I was trying to achieve, although now I see it is perhaps superfluous.

Comment: Sorry, but it is really a shame that this kind of stuff gets on StackOverflow. This is a site that should have quality questions and answers, and this is absolutely wrong code, even if it works for one particular example. You should update your question and specify exactly what you want as output for several examples. Then we can give accurate answers instead of loops that don't loop.

Comment: @trincot So who is StackOverflow for? People that know how to code, or people that are learning how to code? Please take your gatekeeping elsewhere.

Comment: @trincot you're totally right.  Actually this is my fault because I didn't teach him/her.

Comment: @Charcow sorry, I will remove this answer.  Have a good day :-)

Comment: @ele No problem, thank you for your helpful response. Although the for loop was unnecessary, your input resolved my issue and taught me something along the way. I hope most other people on StackOverflow are as kind and helpful.

Comment: @Charcow you're welcome.  Just to clarify, trincot is worry about the community because he wants that everyone share accurate content (question and answer), I mean, he was objective and we must appreciate that. :-)

Comment: @Charcow, I am concerned that you receive correct information. Is that unkind? I have no intention to be nasty. If that is your impression, I am sorry you feel that way. We all want to help, but seek correct answers at all times. It is important to us.

Comment: @Ele, I see the question has been updated with examples. You could try to update your answer in this new light ;-)

Comment: @trincot I am new to StackOverflow, and coding. Your response was far from a warm welcome, but I appreciate the need for preciousness. Perhaps just with a smile :)

Comment: I really hate to split hairs here, but most of your function is still noise. `return arr.slice(howMany)` is all you need. ;)

Comment: @georg hehehe my goodness, I'm still need to read the documentation!!!!

Comment: Good job! ;)...\

Comment: @trincot: "This is a site that should have quality... answers" - so I tried and posted a quality answer (to my best). Did it pay out? Not really.

Comment: Indeed, @georg, that is why I started this comment, as indeed a wrong answer was accepted. Now the situation has improved. I agree that your answer deserves credit. You have my vote. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

For the benefit of future readers, one possible approach to this problem could be like this:

```js
function sliceFrom(sequence, n) {
    let result = [];

    for (let value of sequence)
        if (--n < 0)
            result.push(value);

    if (typeof sequence === 'string')
        return result.join('');

    return result;
}


console.log(sliceFrom('abcdefg', 3));
console.log(sliceFrom([11,22,33,44,55], 2));
console.log(sliceFrom([11,22,33,44,55], 100));
```

Note that, because of using the `of` loop, this "slicer" works with arbitrary sequences (or rather "iterable" values), including those without `.length` property (e.g. `Map` or `Set` objects).

From the practical standpoint, there are built-in methods [`Array.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [`String.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) that do exactly that when invoked with one positive argument. However, our home-made function is *better* than slice when dealing with "astral" characters, e.g. emojis:

```js
function sliceFrom(sequence, n) {
    let result = [];

    for (let value of sequence)
        if (--n < 0)
            result.push(value);

    if (typeof sequence === 'string')
        return result.join('');

    return result;
}

faces = ""

console.log(faces.slice(1))        // not really
console.log(sliceFrom(faces, 1))   // looks fine
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. Please can you explain what would be as 'value' in result.push(value)? many thanks.

Comment: @Charcow: `value` is an element of the sequence, for example for `[a, b, c]`, `value` will take a then b then c.